Jenkins "Physical Memory" is getting full gradually and not freed up resulting in slowness and crash
Recently we have upgraded Jenkins from v2.401.2 to v2.440.1
In this version, we are seeing a lot of issues in terms of resources. On the Java melody (/monitoring page) we are observing that the parameter "Free Physical Memory" is gradually decreasing and once it reaches near exhaustion then we start facing slowness and crash as well.
Heap memory is fine and is never getting full. It's just Physical memory which we suspect is the cause of Jenkin's slowness.
In the previous version total Physical memory was set to 4Gi and it was working fine, now we have increased it to 20Gi still it is getting full, resulting in performance issues.
What can be checked to identify what is holding onto the physical memory and not releasing it?
